# SQL Left Outer Join?

Tags: sql-server, join, left-join, distinct

I have table that should joint to another table based on the unique id. If I do `LEFT OUTER JOIN ON` I will have duplicates. If I put `DISTINCT` in my `SELECT` I will get correct number of records. Then if I include any field from the table that I did `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in that case I'm getting duplicates again. Here is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 Table1.fname,
 Table1.lname,
 Table2.address
FROM Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2
ON Table2.user_id = Table1.userid
```

In the example above I'm getting duplicates, also I have tried to do:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT user_id
  FROM Table2
  GROUP BY user_id
) AS t2 ON Table1.user_id = t2.user_id
```

This gave me correct number of records but I need some additional columns from that second table, after I include extra columns I'm getting duplicates again, example:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT user_id, address
  FROM Table2
  GROUP BY user_id, address
) AS t2 ON Table1.user_id = t2.user_id
```

I'm wondering if I missed something or there is better way to handle this type of problem. If anyone see something or know better solution please let me know.

Comment: What is the Primary Key for Table 2?

Comment: You are getting duplicates from DISTINCT with those additional columns because they have multiple values.  We cannot tell you how to fix it unless you can tell us *which* of those multiple values you want from those columns.

Comment: Can we see some data?

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible for you to pick the correct answer here without understanding your data.

It seems that `Table2` supports multiple `address`es per `user_id`. This is a common design. If you want to return only one `address` per `user_id` you have several options:

1. Fix the data - Remove the duplicate addresses from table 2 and add a constraint that prevents this situation again. You will need to determine which addresses are incorrect.
2. Reduce the left join to only include one address per user - How you do this will depend on your other data. You could use `min()` or `max()` with a `group by` if you don't care which one to return where there are multiples or you will need to perhaps order by an effective date and take the latest one - or maybe there are billing and shipping addresses and you should pick the correct one.
3. Accept that there are multiple addresses per user - this may be correct - and adjust the rest of your code.